# Can we change min / max values of jQuery UI slider in its change event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using this slider. http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.8/Slider

When I move the slider, I'm getting updated max limit. Now i need to apply this new max value to slider too. Will it be changed if I do something like this:

```
$("#slider").slider({
    change: function () {
        .....
        .....
        var btn = document.getElementById('<%=btnUpdate.ClientID%>');
        btn.click();
        $("#slider").slider( "option", "max", newValue);
        .....
}
```

Here I'm using async postback on `btnUpdate` click & in code behind, I'm setting new max limit (which I need to apply to slider) to a hiddenfield.
Will I be able to do this after `btn.click();` statement, in `change` event.

Comment: Are you getting any error? What happens when you try that? Where's the rest of the code? Where does newValue come from? What's its type?

Comment: Why don't you try it and tell us if it worked ?

Comment: not sure your goal, but ti seems like it would be better to use its stop event, then recalculate the max and set it and call a refresh to the widget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The change method will work, but max is going to be reset after you stop dragging.

If you want to change max value while dragging, you should use "slide" event instead of change. Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/nxtwrld/gvSu6/1/

```
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
           $(this).slider("option", "max", newValue);
        }
```

But I would recommend against that, as the the slider will try to fix handle position according to the new max which will collide with dragging the handle and it will start jumping around - as can be seen in the jsfiddle.